# Angular 2 Custom pipe filer issue

Tags: angular, angular2-custom-pipes

I want to filter data according to men and women with custom pipe in employeemale.ts component when I use female in custom pipe in `ngfor` loop it shows data according to female:

Works:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let empLists of empList | filterdata:'female'">
```

but when I use men it shows all the json data

Doesn't work:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let empLists of empList | filterdata:'male'">
```

This is my component html

```
<div class="widget box">
    <div class="widget-header"> <h4><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Female Employe Details</h4></div>
</div>
```

When I filter data according to female it's:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterdata'
})
export class FilterdataPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(empList: Array<any>, arg: string): any {
    debugger
    return empList.filter(function(empLists){
      //console.log(empLists)
           return empLists.gender.toLowerCase().includes(arg.toLowerCase());
    })
  }

}
<div class="widget-content">
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#employee ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
       <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

       <ng-container *ngFor="let empLists of empList | filterdata:'male'">
 <tr>
      <th>{{empLists.id}}</th>
       <th>{{empLists.fullName}}</th>
       <th>{{empLists.gender}}</th>

    </tr>
  </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my custom pipe filterdata.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterdata'
})
export class FilterdataPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(empList: Array<any>, arg: string): any {
    debugger
    return empList.filter(function(empLists){
      //console.log(empLists)
           return empLists.gender.toLowerCase().includes(arg.toLowerCase());
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, male is included into female `return empLists.gender.toLowerCase().includes(arg.toLowerCase());`

Comment: Complete guess, but could it be related to the fact that the word "male" appears within the string "female"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use equality instead of include :

```
transform(empList: Array<any>, arg: string): any {
return empList.filter(function(emp){
  //console.log(empLists)
       return emp.gender.toLowerCase() === arg.toLowerCase();
});
```

Using include will fail because there is a 'male' inside your 'female'